# rails 3 system command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, system

Here is the issue. When running the 'system' command in a rails controller in development it behaves as intended by running the command while in production it does not do anything.

For example the following command:

```
system 'rails g migration user_generated_migration'
```

or even:

```
system 'ls'
```

work locally (in development) but on the server (production environment) they don`t do anything.

Am i missing something in the configuration files, production.rb maybe? Or is there something that should be enabled on the server?

**Update:**

The production environment is the default set up maybe with a notable change to how caching is handled:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, ENV['MEMCACHE_SERVERS']
```

It is running on apache server through passenger. I suspect it has something to do with what rights the apache user has? I don`t have a lot of experience in the server area so i wouldn`t know what exact details to give you.

Comment: Can you describe the production environment a bit more? Are you using a service such as Heroku, Amazon, or your own solution, etc?